# autogenerated id with bulk insert in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite table that uses an autogenerated id as primary key. I want to do bulk inserts using UNION SELECT, but it doesn't seem to be happy unless I specify an id for each row:

```
sqlite> create table CelestialObject (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(25), distance REAL);
sqlite> insert into CelestialObject select 'Betelguese' as name, 200 as distance UNION SELECT 'Procyon', 500;
Error: table CelestialObject has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied
```

If I specify AUTOINCREMENT for the id (i.e., "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT") when I create the table, the error is the same.

Can anyone tell me whether there's a way to use a bulk insert without specifying an id for each row?

Comment: It turns out that you can specify NULL for the id and it will be filled in with the correct one:


`insert into CelestialObject select NULL as id, 'Betelguese' as name, 200 as distance UNION SELECT NULL, 'Procyon', 500;`

Since this works even on older SQLite, there's no need for us to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either provide three values per row:

```
INSERT INTO CelestialObject SELECT NULL, 'x', 42 ...
```

or explicitly specify the columns you want to fill:

```
INSERT INTO CelestialObject(name, distance) SELECT 'x', 42 ...
```

If you have SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can do bulk inserts easier:

```
INSERT INTO CelestialObject(name, distance)
VALUES ('Betelgeose', 200),
       ('Procyon', 500),
       ... ;
```

Comment: I just installed 3.7.14 and used your last suggestion. It worked fine. Thanks! I'll just leave this up for a while and see whether anyone suggests anything else.